# Hi, Does anyone knows how to create the automatic sitemap in liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I have created the sitemp.xml manually.But now I want to create the automatic sitemap in liferay.
Does anyone knows how to create the automatic sitemap in liferay?

Comment: Let me know if you managed to solve your problem and my answer was helpful somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You should

1. Go to content -> configuration -> Application Display Templates
2. Write template either in velocity or freemarker
3. Use site map portlet on your custom page and configure it, using your created custom template.

Here is example of mine:

```
<div>
    <h1>Map service</h1>
    <#assign firstLevelCounter=0>

    <#list entries as secondLvlLayout>

        <#if !secondLvlLayout.isHidden()>
            <#if (firstLevelCounter+1)%2==0>
                <div>
            </#if>

            <div>
                <div><h2>${secondLvlLayout.getName(locale)}</h2></div>
                <#list secondLvlLayout.getChildren() as thirdLvlLayout>

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h3>${thirdLvlLayout.getName(locale)}</h3>
                        </div>

                        <#if thirdLvlLayout.getChildren()?has_content>

                            <ul>
                                <#list thirdLvlLayout.getChildren() as forthLvlLayout>
                                    <li>
                                        <div><a href="${forthLvlLayout.getFriendlyURL(locale)}"><span>${forthLvlLayout.getName(locale)}</span></a></div>
                                    </li>
                                </#list>
                            </ul>

                        </#if>
                    </div>

                </#list>
            </div>

            <#if (firstLevelCounter+1)%2==0>
                </div><hr/>
            </#if>
            <#assign firstLevelCounter=firstLevelCounter+1>

        </#if>

    </#list>
</div>
```